# How do I find a list of the Golem Network Token (GNT) TokenTrader contracts?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, tokens, javascript

The Golem Network Token (GNT) `TokenTrader` contracts enables the trustless and decentralised sale of GNTs for ethers (ETH).

A seller deploys one of these `TokenTrader` contracts using the [`TokenTraderFactory`](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc4af56cd5254aef959d4bce2f75874007808b701#code).`createTradeContract(...)` method, specifying the rate at which they want to sell their GNTs, then top up the contract with GNTs. Instructions from the original author can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/5cnl58/trustless_gnt_selling_contract/d9ycd2a/).

A buyer simply sends ETHs to the seller's deployed `TokenTrader` contract and will receive the GNTs back in the buyer's address.

Further information can be found on https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/trustless-token-selling-contract/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/5cnl58/trustless_gnt_selling_contract/ .

How do I find the list of TokenTrader contracts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Nov 17 2016**

Live updating list of contracts are now available at https://cryptoderivatives.market/.

---

You can find the following script at https://github.com/bokkypoobah/FindGNTTokenTrader/blob/master/findGNTTokenTrader .

```
#!/bin/sh

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find Golem Network Token (GNT) Token Trader information
# 
# Works on Linux and OS/X. May work on Windows with Cygwin.
#
# Usage:
#   1. Download this script to findGNTTokenTrader
#   2. `chmod 700 findGNTTokenTrader`
#   3. Run `geth console` in a window.
#   4. Then run this script `./findGNTTokenTrader` in a separate window.
#
# More information:
#   * https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/trustless-token-selling-contract/
#   * https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/5cnl58/trustless_gnt_selling_contract/
#
# Notes:
#   * This scripts list all deployed TokenTrader, even those deployed with some
#     errors. The Sell price and Units fields for the TokenTrade deployed
#     with errors is normally crazily incorrect
#   * If you do want to try purchasing GNTs from these contracts, test with
#     a small amount first
#
# History:
#   * Nov 14 2016 - Version 1.0
#   * Nov 14 2016 - Version 1.01 - With bookid feedback from /u/JonnyLatte
#   * Nov 14 2016 - Version 1.02 - Getting correct token balance for the 
#                                  TokenTrader contract
#   * Nov 15 2016 - Version 1.03 - Tidy
#   * Nov 15 2016 - Version 1.04 - Getting correct ether balance for the
#                                  TokenTrader contract
#   * Nov 16 2016 - Version 1.05 - CSV and filters
#
# Enjoy. (c) BokkyPooBah 2016. The MIT licence.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DATETIME=`date -u "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%Z"`
TMPFILENAME="/tmp/findGNTTokenTrader.txt";
TXTFILENAME="findGNTTokenTraderOutput_${DATETIME}.txt"
CSVFILENAME="findGNTTokenTraderOutput_${DATETIME}.csv";

geth attach << EOF > $TMPFILENAME

var gntTokenTraderFactoryDeploymentBlock = 2615848;
var gntTokenTraderFactoryAddress = "0xC4aF56cD5254Aef959D4BcE2F75874007808b701";
var gntBookId = "0x2fd64880bc17977672b2e25fff32b433975c4004b4fbd094936429e92f58d39f";
var gntTokenTraderFactoryABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_asset","type":"address"},{"name":"_sellPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_units","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"name":"createTradeContract","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"tradeContract","type":"address"}],"name":"verify","outputs":[{"name":"valid","type":"bool"},{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"sellPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"units","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"payable":false,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"bookid","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"addr","type":"address"}],"name":"TradeListing","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"bookid","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"units","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewBook","type":"event"}];
var gntTokenTraderABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[{"name":"ok","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"asset","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"sellPrice","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"sellsTokens","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawAsset","outputs":[{"name":"ok","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"units","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_token","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawToken","outputs":[{"name":"ok","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"buy","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"name":"activate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_asset","type":"address"},{"name":"_sellPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_units","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"sells","type":"bool"}],"name":"ActivatedEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"UpdateEvent","type":"event"}];
var gntTokenABIFragment = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}];
var erc20ABIFragment = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}];
var minimumSellPrice = 0.0001;
var maximumSellPrice = 100000000;

var gntTokenTraderFactoryInterface = web3.eth.contract(gntTokenTraderFactoryABI).at(gntTokenTraderFactoryAddress);
var tradeListingEvent = gntTokenTraderFactoryInterface.TradeListing({valueA: gntBookId}, {fromBlock: gntTokenTraderFactoryDeploymentBlock, toBlock: 'latest'});
var i = 0;
var now = new Date();
console.log("Data: Listing generated at " + now.toUTCString()); 
console.log("CSV: #,TokenTraderAddress,SellsTokens,EtherPer1000Tokens,TokenBalance,Block,Deployed,TxHash,Owner,Asset,Symbol,SellPrice,Units," +
  "TokenTraderEtherBalance,OwnerEtherBalance");  
tradeListingEvent.watch(function (error, result) {
    try {
      var tokenTrader = web3.eth.contract(gntTokenTraderABI).at(result.args.addr);
      var assetAddress = tokenTrader.asset();
      var sellPrice = tokenTrader.sellPrice();
      if ("0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d" == assetAddress &&
          sellPrice >= minimumSellPrice &&
          sellPrice <= maximumSellPrice) {
        console.log("Data: " + i + " TokenTrader Address: " + result.args.addr);
        var block = eth.getBlock(result.blockNumber);
        var deployedAt = new Date(block.timestamp * 1000);
        console.log("Data:   Deployed                         : #" + result.blockNumber + " at " + deployedAt.toUTCString());
        console.log("Data:   TxHash                           : " + result.transactionHash);
        console.log("Data:   Owner                            : " + result.args.owner);
        var ercInterface = web3.eth.contract(erc20ABIFragment).at(assetAddress);
        var symbol;
        try {
          symbol = ercInterface.symbol();
        } catch (e) {
          symbol = "???";
        }
        console.log("Data:   Asset address                    : " + assetAddress + " " + symbol);
        var sellsTokens = tokenTrader.sellsTokens();
        console.log("Data:   Sells tokens                     : " + sellsTokens);
        console.log("Data:   Sell price                       : " + sellPrice);
        var units = tokenTrader.units();
        console.log("Data:   Units                            : " + units);
        console.log("Data:   Ethers per 1,000 tokens          : " + sellPrice.div(units).mul(1000));
        var asset = web3.eth.contract(gntTokenABIFragment).at(assetAddress);
        // Does not work
        // var originalTokenBalance = asset.balanceOf(result.args.addr, result.blockNumber);
        // console.log("Data:   Tokens balance at creation    : " + originalTokenBalance.div(1e18));
        var tokenBalance = asset.balanceOf(result.args.addr);
        console.log("Data:   Current TokenTrader token balance: " + tokenBalance.div(1e18));
        var tokenTraderEtherBalance = eth.getBalance(result.args.addr);
        console.log("Data:   Current TokenTrader ether balance: " + tokenTraderEtherBalance.div(1e18));
        var ownerEtherBalance = eth.getBalance(result.args.owner);
        console.log("Data:   Current Owner ether balance      : " + ownerEtherBalance.div(1e18));
      
        // var updateEvent = tokenTrader.UpdateEvent({}, {fromBlock: result.blockNumber, toBlock: 'latest'});
        // updateEvent.watch(function (error1, result1) {
        //   console.log("    " + JSON.stringify(result1));
        // });
        // updateEvent.stopWatching();
        console.log("CSV: " + i + "," + result.args.addr + "," + sellsTokens + "," + 
          sellPrice.div(units).mul(1000) + "," + tokenBalance.div(1e18) + "," + 
          result.blockNumber + "," + deployedAt.toUTCString() + "," + 
          result.transactionHash + "," + result.args.owner + "," + 
          assetAddress + "," + symbol + "," + sellPrice + "," + units + "," +           
          tokenTraderEtherBalance.div(1e18) + "," + ownerEtherBalance.div(1e18));
        console.log(i++ + ": " + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Data:   Cannot get details for TokenTrader " + e);
    }
});
tradeListingEvent.stopWatching();

EOF

grep "Data:" $TMPFILENAME | sed "s/Data: //" > $TXTFILENAME
grep "CSV:" $TMPFILENAME | sed "s/CSV: //" | grep -v "false" > $CSVFILENAME
```

### Notes

- This scripts list all deployed TokenTrader, even those deployed with some errors. The Sell price and Units fields for the TokenTrade deployed with errors is normally crazily incorrect.
- If you do want to try purchasing GNTs from these contracts, test with  a small amount first.
- This is just a tool for finding the contracts. Your use of the contracts is your own responsibility!

The latest listing in tabular format https://github.com/bokkypoobah/FindGNTTokenTrader/blob/master/findGNTTokenTraderOutput_20161115_200640UTC.csv, with the active market below:

```
#,TokenTraderAddress,SellsTokens,EtherPer1000Tokens,TokenBalance
26,0x4b17f65fc6450cbcced9e893dd84123a5fc13362,TRUE,1.45,154913.0693
27,0x1e00980cb7b109d290fcf6c4e579debb8c836c39,TRUE,1.45,329983.1034
24,0x1a22bb6827dbb7df60a6de726519c2a509271695,TRUE,1.5,580393.55
6,0xc0081f0e16cbceec6df8e63986212a52ee493540,TRUE,1.88,102821.2909
23,0x406a65de7a2e94ef19597a79296e269fada85a71,TRUE,1.9,136166.8742
15,0x5eb860c816789bb52300a0675300701eca203cf8,TRUE,1.95,158854.1026
0,0x399156ee3339f4b29a53e307b98cce09fda3bac7,TRUE,2,5430.015
10,0xa7f8da2594eaf1e8573a5974be6028f64157cd7a,TRUE,2,713516
22,0xf31057bc0ff5e3e3b32652b29c0451624392567c,TRUE,2,100050
25,0xffd41efe3d3c073f4c7dbf2cec7c19111fc7523e,TRUE,2,4250
17,0x6e3f7ad4d9accb12452744fb2785ecac31ea8026,TRUE,2.05,50000
18,0x4b34da26bfb35d3089c455cb483a5fff8695d447,TRUE,2.11,200000
11,0x42be3b481f25b0148cd1a144d8ca22cda5b677e7,TRUE,2.33,9.00E-12
2,0x4104e4b12e73bc99dd4f20a39525d07aa395c0d4,TRUE,3,1794.833333
19,0x593fd4a14f64282891a1369442462361a1908b01,TRUE,3.75,900
```